# Error in building a react native project on mac os

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, macos

When building a project on react native on macOS, it gives an error: Unhandled JS Exception: Property 'queueMicrotask' doesn't exist ReferenceError: Property 'queueMicrotask' doesn't exist at anonymous...

I tried the npm update command, also cleared the cache and updated pods

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.